# Cosine similarity yields 'nan' values

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix, similarity, cosine-similarity

I was calculating a Cosine Similarity Matrix for sparse vectors, and the elements expected to be float numbers appeared to be 'nan'.

'visits' is a sparse matrix showing how many times each user has visited each website. This matrix used to have a shape 1 500 000 x 1500, but I converted it into sparse matrix, using coo_matrix().tocsc().

The task is to find out, how similar the websites are, so I decided to calculate the cosine metric between each two sites.

Here is my code:

```
cosine_distance_matrix = np.ndarray(shape = (visits.shape[1], visits.shape[1]))

def norm(x):
return np.sqrt(
    x.T.dot(x)
)

for i in range(0, visits.shape[1]):
  for k in range(0, i + 1):
    normi_normk = norm(visits[:,i]) * norm(visits[:,k])
    cosine_distance_matrix[i,k] = visits[:,i].T.dot(visits[:, k])/normi_normk
    cosine_distance_matrix[k, i] = cosine_distance_matrix[i, k]

print cosine_distance_matrix
```

And this is what I have gotten! O_o

```
[[  1.  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan   1.  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan   1. ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 ..., 
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,   1.  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan   1.  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan   1.]]
```

This program was running for 3 hours... What's the reason of such a trash instead of float numbers?

Comment: NaN is a float, it's just not the float you're looking for.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN for more on NaNs.  One way to get them is zero divided by zero.  I suggest posting a short, self-contained, correct example (based on what you've already posted) that shows the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def norm(x):
    return np.sqrt((x.T*x).A)
```

I constructed a smaller sample `visits` matrix, and calculated `cosine_distance_matrix` with your code.  Mine had the diagonal of 1s, and lots of `nan` on the off diagonal.  I choose one of the `nan` items, and looked the the corresponding `i,k` calculation.

```
In [690]: normi_normk = norm(visits[:,i]) * norm(visits[:,k])
In [691]: normi_normk
Out[691]: 
<1x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
In [692]: normi_normk.A
Out[692]: array([[ 18707.57953344]])
```

`visits` is a sparse matrix, so `visits[:,i]` is also sparse matrix (1 column).  Your `norm` function returns a 1x1 sparse matrix.

For this pair, this `dot` is 0, but it still a 1x1 sparse matrix:

```
In [718]: visits[:,i].T.dot(visits[:, k])
Out[718]: 
<1x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

The division of these sparse matricies is also sparse - and `nan`.

```
In [717]: visits[:,i].T.dot(visits[:, k])/normi_normk
Out[717]: matrix([[ nan]])
```

But if I change `normi_normk` to a scalar or dense array I get 0

```
In [722]: visits[:,i].T.dot(visits[:, k])/normi_normk.A
Out[722]: matrix([[ 0.]])
```

So we have to change this from a `matrix/matrix` division, to something involving dense arrays or scalars.   It can be changed in various ways.  Rewriting the `norm` to handle sparse matrices correctly is one.

In addition I'd suggest using:

```
(visits[:,i].T*visits[:, k]).A/normi_normk
```

so that both terms of the division are dense.

Another possibility is to use `visits[:,i].A` and `visits[:,k].A`, so the inner loop calculations are done with dense arrays rather than these matrices.

Note that I'm not doing anything advanced or special.  I just examined in detail one of the problem calculations, and found the source of the `nan`.

---

I would also suggest using `np.zeros` to initialize the array.  I only use `ndarray` when the normal `zeros`, `ones`, `empty` don't work.

```
cosine_distance_matrix = np.zeros((visits.shape[1], visits.shape[1]))
```

---

In the big picture it would best to avoid looping over `i` and `k`, doing everything with matrix products and such.  But this fix will get you going.