# Cosine similarity yields 'nan' values pt.II

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

This is the other side of this question: [Cosine similarity yields 'nan' values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651788/cosine-similarity-yields-nan-values) .
In that topic, auther coded the metrics by himself, but iam using scipy's cosine: (`ratings` is 71869x10000)

```
A = ratings[:,100]
A = A.reshape(1,A.shape[0])
books_similarity = np.empty([1, ratings.shape[0]])

for book in range(10000):
    books_similarity[0,book] = -cosine(A, ratings[:,book].reshape(1,A.shape[1]))+1
```

BUT it outputs: 0, one 1(for for itself) and NaN. So the solution in the topic i mentioned before, is not for me, becuase, iam using scipy. What should i do?

P.S: then i delete "1" from array and do:

```
m = np.argmax(books_similarity)
books_similarity[0,m]
```

It returns "NaN"

P.S.S: First, i had a pickle file, decoded it into CSR, but then used numpy. I think, i should consider everything as np arrays, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cosine distance is not defined if one of the input vectors is all 0.  [`scipy.spatial.distance.cosine`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html) returns `nan` in that case:

```
In [70]: a
Out[70]: array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])

In [71]: b
Out[71]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

In [72]: cosine(a, b)
/Users/warren/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py:329: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  dist = 1.0 - np.dot(u, v) / (norm(u) * norm(v))
Out[72]: nan
```

This may be happening in your code.  Before calling `cosine`, check that neither input is all 0.

---

P.S. I haven't tried to decipher what you are doing with `A` and `ratings`, but I suspect you'll eventually want to use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) with the argument `method='cosine'`.

Comment: Its usefull, but, thats defenitly what is not happenning in my code. All vectros have at least one "1" element

Comment: Can you find a specific pair of vectors that result in `nan`?  If so, please add that to the question.  Without your data, all we can do is guess.